# Can I compute Haar-features using "Coefficients" in a IntegralKernel defined filter instead of integralFilter() function?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction, matlab-cvst

I define a Haar-like feature filter **H** by the **IntegralKernel** class in Matlab.

```
H = integralKernel(integralKernel([1,1,im_width,im_height;...
                                   2, 2, w, h;...
                                   2+w, 2, w, h;],...
                                   [0,1,-1]);
```

*im_width* and *im_height* are width and height of the image; *w* and *h* are width and height of the bounding box of the filter. The returned filte **H** is a Matlab **struct** type variable, which contains the fields like:

```
BoundingBoxes
Weights
Coefficients - Conventional filter coefficients.
Center
Size
```

In Matlab document, it uses the function **integralFilter(IntegralImage, H)**, when computing the feature from the given integral image. The code is like:

```
HaarFeature = integralFilter(integralImage(I), H)
```

But this takes a long time if the number of images are large (e.g., 10,000 images), because I need to use a **for-loop** to compute every image. However, I found that is much quicker if I just compute the sum of the given original image **I** and the **coefficients** in the filer **H**. The code is like:

```
HaarFeature = sum(sum(I .* H.Coefficients));
```

Both **I** and **H.Coefficients** are *double* type in Matlab.

My question is that if these two ways to compute the Haar Features are equivalent? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to filter each image with multiple kernels?
In that case you should only call `integralImage(I)` once for each image, and store and re-use the result. Computing the integral image takes some time. However, once you have it, applying an integral kernel to the resulting integral image should be very fast.

Comment: Hi @Dima, in my case, one image is required to be filtered by 1000 Haar features, where each feature has the randomly selected location on the image and has randomly scales. That is, for example, image **I** and its integral image **intIM**, I need to compute the 1000 features for **I** by calling function **integralFilter(intIM, Hi)** with different filters **Hi** for 1000 times. My question is can I just built a (im_height,im_width, 1000) array **Ha** to store the 1000 features coefficients and use the original image **I** .* **Ha** to compute the 1000 features at one time? Thanks!